# AWS Amplify Auth.SignOut crashing Expo Go

Tags: react-native, authentication, expo, aws-amplify, stack-navigator

I'm currently working on a project using React Native, Expo, and AWS Amplify.  On my project's Home Screen exists a log out button that invokes *Auth.signOut()* from Amplify's Auth class.  The button successfully logs out the user (my sign-in page automatically redirects to the Home Screen if a user is authenticated-- this doesn't occur after the log out button is pressed), but it crashes the app in doing so.  I'm using Expo Go (and testing on iOS currently) as the emulator for the app.  How would I implement this so that the app doesn't crash upon logging out?  Below is an image of the implementation of this code:

```
const App = () => {
  const logOut = async () => {
    try {
      await Auth.signOut();
      navigation.navigate('Sign In')
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert("Error Signing Out, please try again.", error)
    }
  }
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor} loading={null}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{...}}>
            <Stack.Screen name="Sign In" component={SignInScreen}/>
            ...
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={({navigation}) => 
              ({ headerRight: () =>
                <IconButton icon={props => <Icon name="logout" size={30} onPress={logOut}/>}/>,
              headerLeft: null, gestureEnabled: false})}
            />
            ...
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App
```

I've also tried using the useAuthenticator hook to achieve this, but have had the same result.  In regards to what I'm expecting, I would expect the *navigation.navigate('Home')* statement to direct the screen to the Sign In Screen rather than crashing Expo Go.